# Force Customer to register in Magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

What can I do if I want the customer to register in the check out process?
Is there any simple way to do it?
[image: magento1.9 onepage checkout]
I want the user register from the billing information where users are required to fill in the password and email.

Comment: Please check the official Magento documentation about this one thing: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Allow Guest Checkout` to `No` in 
`Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout`

Comment: I wanna add a check out step where user can register in that check out step. It is hard to build one? Or can I just copy the registration module to there?

Comment: This is default behaviour. Login or Register is displayed upon checkout.

Comment: @techjam, I have updated my questions . Please check